# Django, CreateView: pass form argument to reverse_lazy

Tags: python, django

To redirect the user after filling out the CreateView form I would like to access an argument from the form and pass it to the reverse_lazy function.
**How can I access the parameters of the form within CreateView**?

I actually use the argument I'm looking for to pass it to the form itself (`self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER').split('/')[-1]`), but seem not to be able to use this logic in reverse_lazy.

get_form_kwargs also seems not to achieve the result:

**views.py**

```
class PieceInstanceCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = PieceInstance
    fields = ['version', 'piece_image', 'status']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.piece = Piece.objects.get(id=self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER').split('/')[-1])
        return super(PieceInstanceCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(PieceInstanceCreate, self).get_form_kwargs()
        return kwargs['piece']

    success_url = reverse_lazy('piece-detail', kwargs={'pk': get_form_kwargs(self)})
```

**urls.py**

```
path('piece/<int:pk>', views.PieceDetailView.as_view(), name='piece-detail')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't pass it to reverse_lazy. Instead of using `success_url`, you should define the `get_success_url` method, which allows you to create the URL dynamically using whatever parameters you want.

However there are few other things wrong with your code here. Firstly, you should not be trying to do all that calculation based on the HTTP_REFERER attribute. If your view needs a piece of information, you should pass it in the URL as a keyword parameter, which you can then get in your view by using `self.kwargs`. In your case it looks like your view already has the pk argument; you can use `self.kwargs['pk']`.

Given that, your `get_success_url` method would look like:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('piece-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']})
```

Secondly, your `get_form_kwargs` method will always give a KeyError; the super method won't return a dictionary with a "piece" key, and even if it did the method must return a dict, not an individual value, including all the relevant items like the actual POST data. Again it's not clear what you are trying to do with this method; since you don't specify a custom form, it doesn't need custom kwargs. You should remove this method altogether.

Finally, you don't need to call `form.save()` inside your form_valid method, even with commit=False. A CreateView already assigns an instance to the form, so you can just do `form.instance.piece = ...`.

Comment: Thanks for all the inputs! I added a new answer to show the reworked class.

Comment: Additional tip: If you looking for the logged in user, use:
 reverse_lazy('profile', kwargs={'pk': self.request.user.pk})

Answer (score 1):

Here the reworked and working class (using the inputs from @DanielRoseman):

```
class PieceInstanceCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = PieceInstance
    fields = ['version', 'piece_image', 'status']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.piece = Piece.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return super(PieceInstanceCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('piece-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']})
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that when you use CBV
Just see this example:

models.py

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('author-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

views.py

```
class AuthorCreate(CreateView):
    model = Author
    fields = ['name']
```